# Unexpected very slow user count in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress page that returns timeout error every so often. When reviewing the MySQL "slow queries" log, I could notice that there is an extremely slow query coming from Wordpress, but I don't know exactly which module:

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpe_users.*
    FROM  wpe_users
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  wpe_users.ID IN (
        SELECT  DISTINCT wpe_posts.post_author
            FROM  wpe_posts
            WHERE  wpe_posts.post_status = 'publish'
              AND  wpe_posts.post_type IN ( 'post', 'page', 'attachment',
                        'wp_block', 'products' ) 
                          )
    ORDER BY  display_name ASC
    LIMIT  0, 10;
```

The query appears two or more times, with State `Copying to tmp table` and Time of up to 53815.44 (secs? 15 hours? it's crazy!). And it makes the Mysql process consume 557% of CPU and 8.7% of RAM

[image: Server Error and Mysql Process List]

The `wpe_users` table contains almost 3 million entries and the `wpe_posts` table contains 68,000 entries. The `wpe_comments` table is also starting to cause problems as it contains 361,000 entries.

**I use pagination for comments and posts but not for users. The question is, how can I fix the problem without disabling paging? How can I identify where the user query is coming from if I don't show users anywhere?**

**What have I tried?**

- I updated Wordpress to the latest version available.
- I tried to identify where these queries come from using the "Query Monitor" plugin but they don't appear.
- I verified the only 3 plugins that I have active and none of them generate such queries.
- I closed the administration panel and killed said processes to see if the queries were generated by the administration panel but they start again...

I don't have much experience with MySQL configuration. I am using MySQL 5.5.62 with Plesk panel on a VPS 5GB RAM 6 Cores

**SHOW CREATE TABLE wpe_users**

```
CREATE TABLE `wpe_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_login` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_nicename` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `display_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`),
  KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3492068 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**EXPLAIN wpe_users query**

```
+----+--------------------+-----------+-------+------------------------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table     | type  | possible_keys                | key              | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                        |
+----+--------------------+-----------+-------+------------------------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | wpe_users | ALL   | NULL                         | NULL             | NULL    | NULL | 2780982 | Using where; Using filesort  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wpe_posts | range | type_status_date,post_author | type_status_date | 164     | NULL |    2265 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+--------------------+-----------+-------+------------------------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Not sure how much help this will be, but that query is sent to the database on line 2927 of `/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php`. It's built right into the `get_posts()` function which is arguably the most important block of code in the entire package ...

Comment: 5.5.62 is a very old version of MySQL (very unsupported). Why has this only shown up now? You could take your backup and restore to a newer MySQL or MariaDB version and see if it gets better performance on the same query. Use `EXPLAIN {query}` to see how its going to execute and compare this to your existing server.

Comment: @danblack Thank you, I will do that. This problem is not new, I have had it for more than two years, and it was the reason why I left the project. Now I'm going back to it and I want to solve this problem that brought me so many headaches, wordpress gets saturated and crashes all the time.

Comment: 557% of CPU, that's a lot :)

Comment: The offending query shows the first ten authors by name. With three million users, that seems pointless. Does your theme have such a leaderboard anyplace? @danblack correctly pointed out that mysql v 5.5 is more than a decade old, and reached end-of-life in 2018.  Tell your hosting provider to upgrade, or dump them for a better one. Seriously. Later versions have many performance improvements, including for the query pattern `ID IN (SELECT...)`. And try tidying up your database with a plugin like [Advanced Database Cleaner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-database-cleaner/).

Answer (score 2):

Add this composite index to `wpe_posts`:  `INDEX(post_status, post_type, post_author)`.

The answer to "why":  In 5.5 (and before), `IN ( SELECT ... )` was a terribly slow construct.

Amd see if this runs faster:

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpe_users.*
    FROM  ( SELECT  DISTINCT post_author
            FROM  wpe_posts
            WHERE  post_status = 'publish'
              AND  post_type IN ( 'post', 'page', 'attachment',
                        'wp_block', 'products' ) 
          ) AS x
    JOIN wpe_users USING wpe_users.ID = x.post_author
    ORDER BY  display_name ASC
    LIMIT  0, 10;
```

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Be aware that a future version is likely to remove the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` feature, forcing you to make two `SELECTs`.

Comment: This query is made by Wordpress and I am not sure what its function is, I would like to avoid it but I cannot identify what generates it ...

Comment: I gotta chime in. (1) 3 megausers is *really* a lot for the way WordPress is designed. (2) For a site with this many users, your chance of success is quite low unless you upgrade to MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.3+, (3) Rick James and I have created a WordPress plugin to give the tables better indexes. https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/ . It indexes `wpe_users.display_name` which might help this `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` antipattern. But `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is still going to force a table scan. It may be time for another plugin that rewrites bad queries. Whatta mess.  Sigh.

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is deprecated.  So, rethink the need for the total row count.